# Apache Sling stops responding to requests

Tags: java, jetty, jackrabbit, sling

I used apache sling to create a WCMS and I deployed it on a virtual server.

Sometimes apache sling does not responsd any request and it seems to be in a sleep or hibernate mode (when call a url of WCMS nothing happens!!!).

I think this issue occurs when sling has no request for a long time period e.g. several days.

Is it a connection pool and timeout issue?

How can I fix it?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Take a thread dump of the application threads and post it/link it here.

Comment: Thx, how could I do this? I don't use any thread directly.

Comment: See http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/TakeThreadDump.html

Answer (score 2):

Cherry-picking some information from the [discussion on the Sling users' list](http://markmail.org/thread/mn3yih6zpjgtiwyo):

- A thread dump was posted at http://pastebin.com/nhQFxXUK
- This is a deadlock in the Jetty NIO code, so a further question is
  what version of the org.apache.felix.http.jetty bundle do you use? You
  might get rid of this bug by upgrading to the latest released version
  ( 2.2.1 ) .
- If you can't do that, you can tell Jetty not to use NIO ( Felix Web
  Console -> Comopnents -> 'Apache Felix Jetty Based Http Service' and
  uncheck the 'NIO for HTTP', 'NIO for HTTPS' ).

Comment: I updated the bundle to version 2.2.1. I hope this works.
Any way, thanks for your help.